# Ошибка: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, openpyxl

Есть код для работы с Excel:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('D:\lab_report.xlsx')
sht = wb.active
sht.unmerge_cells('C31:D31')
rep = sht['C31'].value
for i in range(45,500):
    if sht['AX'+ str(i)].value > 0:
        sht['AY' + str(i)] = rep
    else:
        break
wb.save('D:\lab_report.xlsx')
```

При выполнении выдает ошибку:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Столбец в условии содержит строго числа.

Не могу разобраться.

Comment: замените `if sht['AX'+ str(i)].value > 0` -> `if sht['AX'+ str(i)].value and sht['AX'+ str(i)].value > 0`

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо, сработало! только я так и не понял почему. могли бы вы объяснить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В ячейках Excel файла могут быть пустые значения, представленные как `None` в OpenPyxl.

Как и сказано в ошибке, `None` нельзя сравнивать с объектами титпа `int`.  Воспроизведение ошибки:

```
if None > 0:
    print("oops!")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Поэтому сначала нужно сделать проверку не является ли объект `None`:

```
if sht['AX{i}'+ str(i)].value is not None and sht['AX'+ str(i)].value > 0:
```

а еще лучше / понятнее сделать так (для Python 3.8+):

```
for i in range(45,500):
    if (val := sht[f'AX{i}'].value) is None or val <= 0: 
        break
    sht[f'AX{i}'] = rep
```

Comment: проверка нужна, потому что эти значение не находятся в памяти? Просто первый раз столкнулся с необходимостью такой.

Comment: @Dmitry, расписал подробно в ответе) Как объяснить еще понятнее - не представляю :-D

Comment: @Dmitry, нет, т.к. эти типы нельзя сравнивать как больше или меньше. `None` это пустая ссылка (т.е. буквально `"ничего"`), а `0` объект целого типа

Comment: Прочел ответ, пропустил видимо первую строку. Теперь понятно:)

Comment: @MaxU Ещё короче будет, если всю эту колбасу сохранить в переменную и проверять уже переменную )  При дублировании кода легко ошибиться кроме всего прочего

Comment: @CrazyElf, да здравствует `walrus operator` ! ;)

Comment: @MaxU Ну, в данном случае можно и обычной переменной обойтись, вот если дело внутри однострочного `for` происходит, там уже да )

Comment: @CrazyElf, в том-то все и дело - эта переменная нужна только в строке проверки. Создавать еще одну переменную - городить ненужную сущность